# How to troubleshoot Nginx file download slow down of response time

Tags: nginx, download

We have a file server that uses Nginx as a front end. It is responding to https file download requests of zip files made every few minutes from applications (python, ruby scripts, other tools, etc). Most of the time the response time ($response_time output to log) to complete the download of the zip file takes less than 1 second. Every once in a while (this recent occurrence has started after several months of no occurrences of this issue), something starts causing the response time for a file (not every occurrence of download attempt) to start taking longer and longer it starts creeping upward slowly - watching an instance of this now in the log of a download taking > 20 seconds - while then bouncing around between less than 1 second and then 5 , 10 etc seconds. The file size does change minimally (another process is updating the file on the server from another source) but it is not increasing by any amount that would correlate with these request time download duration increases.

My sense is that it is some sort of caching or i/o issue and if I restart Nginx I believe it will resolve the issue - however I am not sure how to best troubleshoot this to get to the underlying problem and fix it. I am holding off just brute force restarting Nginx so I can use the current situation to troubleshoot. I need to understand what is the best approach, process and perhaps commands and tools available to troubleshoot what is happening and where the source of the problem is.

The layers are:

- Imperva Cloud WAF (caching disabled for site I believe but even still it is only keeping 5 minutes maximum)
- Cisco ASA Firewall
- Docker on Dell Server with plenty of resources using Ubuntu as host OS

  - Nginx Reverse Proxy container (jwilder nginx-proxy)
  - Nginx File Server container using alpine:3.9 as base image os (file system is bind mounted volume to host server file system)

fileserver config file: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
log_format apm '"$time_local" $request_time $remote_user '
                '$connection $connection_requests '
                '"$request" '
                '$request_length '
                '$status '
                '$bytes_sent '
                '$body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_user_agent" '
                '"$http_range" "$sent_http_content_range"';

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /srv/data;

    client_max_body_size 1G;

    auth_basic  "Access restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/config/.htpasswd;

    location /fancyindex {
        rewrite /fancyindex/(.*) /$1  break;
        root /theme;
    }

    # problem existed before making use of fancyindex module so it is not culprit
    fancyindex on;
    fancyindex_show_path   on;
    fancyindex_name_length 255;
    fancyindex_exact_size  off;
    fancyindex_localtime   on;
    fancyindex_header "/fancyindex/header.html";
    fancyindex_footer "/fancyindex/footer.html";
    fancyindex_ignore "fancyindex";
    fancyindex_ignore "\.partialdownload$";
    fancyindex_hide_parent_dir on;

    add_header X-myuri "$uri";
    add_header X-myrequest_uri "$request_uri";

    location / {            
      error_log  /srv/logs/error.log warn;
      access_log  /srv/logs/access.log apm;
      expires -1;
      alias /srv/data/fileserver/;
      try_files $remote_user$uri \
                $remote_user$uri/
                =404;
          }
                            
    location /theme {
        alias /theme;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
      return 204;
      access_log     off;
      log_not_found  off;
    }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  sendfile off;
  sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
  tcp_nopush on;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  #
  #
  gzip on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
  gunzip on;

}
```

Normally the response_time is consistently throughout the day less than 1 second but this sample snippet from the log output for a particular file for a particular user (2nd column is $request_time) shows what I am seeing during one of these points in time where it starts taking very long to complete the download request:

```
"08/Jun/2022:05:32:03 -0700" 0.522 user123 3177390 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28080171 28079749 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:05:42:04 -0700" 0.772 user123 3177516 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078183 28077761 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:05:52:08 -0700" 3.218 user123 3177646 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078450 28078028 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:02:04 -0700" 0.432 user123 3177772 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28080571 28080149 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:12:03 -0700" 0.479 user123 3177898 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28080002 28079580 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:22:05 -0700" 1.543 user123 3178028 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28077749 28077327 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:32:04 -0700" 0.928 user123 3178154 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078910 28078488 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:42:05 -0700" 1.474 user123 3178280 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078441 28078019 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:06:52:04 -0700" 0.480 user123 3178410 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078441 28078019 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:02:06 -0700" 0.915 user123 3178536 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 441 200 28078441 28078019 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:12:06 -0700" 1.396 user123 3178662 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28078441 28078019 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:22:08 -0700" 3.366 user123 3178792 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28079029 28078607 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:32:25 -0700" 13.051 user123 3178918 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28075724 28075302 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:42:33 -0700" 24.602 user123 3179044 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28076911 28076489 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:07:52:32 -0700" 20.164 user123 3179174 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28076041 28075619 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:02:39 -0700" 21.519 user123 3179302 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28075653 28075231 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:12:21 -0700" 10.770 user123 3179428 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28072422 28072000 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:22:14 -0700" 4.246 user123 3179558 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28073981 28073559 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:32:06 -0700" 1.478 user123 3179684 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28076458 28076036 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:42:45 -0700" 19.535 user123 3179810 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28071973 28071551 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:08:52:09 -0700" 3.198 user123 3179940 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28072256 28071834 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:02:12 -0700" 5.108 user123 3180066 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28072000 28071578 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:12:33 -0700" 20.792 user123 3180192 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28071737 28071315 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:22:06 -0700" 1.093 user123 3180322 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28069271 28068849 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:32:08 -0700" 2.043 user123 3180448 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28069252 28068830 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:42:10 -0700" 3.513 user123 3180574 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28070275 28069853 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:09:52:11 -0700" 4.297 user123 3180704 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28069465 28069043 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:10:02:08 -0700" 0.692 user123 3180830 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28069603 28069181 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:10:12:14 -0700" 7.634 user123 3180956 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28066005 28065583 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:10:22:29 -0700" 13.836 user123 3181086 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28066075 28065653 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:10:32:35 -0700" 27.740 user123 3181212 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28065623 28065201 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
"08/Jun/2022:10:42:04 -0700" 0.742 user123 3181338 1 "GET /system_inventory.zip HTTP/1.1" 442 200 28066297 28065875 "python-requests/2.27.1" "-" "-"
```

If it just restart Nginx the problem may go away but I loose the opportunity to understand and resolve the issue.

I am looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot further than I already have to narrow the problem down to a culprit that can be resolved. Some sort of test or command or monitoring step or identifying something in the configuration file that stands out.